# Split tags in environment and question tag - to prevent "do not use this tag for..."

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-experience

There are multiple tags which have in the description some kind of warning, like "Do not use this tag" ([visual-studio-2015 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2015/info)), 
"Use this tag only if" ([windows tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/info)) and 
"Do not use this tag for" ([github tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github/info)).

IMO this isn't really working, as I see a lot of users who are using those tags wrong. Also I see edits that will only remove those tags.

Furthermore some of those edits goes wrong as only the tag is removed while it could be valuable information for the question. E.g. it could be relevant if someone is using Visual Studio 2015, Windows 64 etc.

But maybe it's not that intuitive for users, so my proposal: split the tags in "environment tags" and "question tags". The user would see another tags box for the "environment tags".

Comment: Not sure how helpful this would be.  I could see 1.5K+ users adding tags into the questions tag that should be in the environment tag because they do not show up.  I can't tell you the number of times I see people add a tag to a question and the very first thing is *DO NOT USE THIS TAG.  IT IS BEING REMOVED*, and it is not just new users that do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrong tags are annoying. It's also annoying that there is no mechanism where the community can blacklist certain tags (like [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework)), although each of the tags you mention has its proper use.

> Also I see edits that will only remove those tags.
>
> Furthermore some of those edits goes wrong as only the tag is removed while it could be valuable information for the question.

If you see this happening, you can always reject the edit with the 'causes harm' reason, or rollback if it has already been approved.

> Split the tags in "environment tags" and "question tags". The user would see another tags box, for the "environment tags".

I don't think this will solve the problem. Users apparently aren't reading the tag excerpts at all, so it doesn't matter if you give the box another format. Users *just don't read*.

Comment: Well it's now also a bit hidden of course.